# Please write a query for this case

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLITE and I have come across with a situation for which I couldn't find any query.

Please write a query for this case.

**Table - A:**

```
Name Class RollNo

ab     2     1
bc     2     2
cd     2     3
```

**Table - B:**

```
Sport Grade RollNo

wx     A     2
xy     B     3
yz     C     4
zz     D     5
```

Let's assume these two are the tables..

I need a query which returns the following table:

```
Name Class RollNo Sport Grade

ab     2     1      
bc     2     2     wx      A
cd     2     3     xy      B
             4     yz      C
             5     zz      D
```

I hope you understood what I meant by the last table;
all the roll numbers should be present in the result table ...........

And one more time I'm using **SQLITE**.

Comment: You should use FULL OUTER JOIN. But i am not sure if it exists in sqllite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` of `left join` and `right join` (but it is [not implemented yet in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)) so instead the `right join` use `left join` with interchanged tables:

```
select * from (
    select a.name, a.class, coalesce(a.rollNo, b.rollNo) as rollNo, b.sport, b.grade
    from tableA a
    left join tableB b on a.rollNo = b.rollNo
    union
    select a.name, a.class, coalesce(a.rollNo, b.rollNo) as rollNo, b.sport, b.grade
    from tableB b
    left join tableA a on b.rollNo = a.rollNo
) t
order by rollNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to perform a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which isn't directly supported in SQLLITE but you can achieve the same effect using UNION'd LEFT JOINS.

```
SELECT a.Name, a.class, a.rollNo, b.support, b.grade
FROM   TABLE-A a 
       LEFT JOIN TABLE-B b 
          ON a.RollNo = b.RollNo
UNION ALL
SELECT a.Name, a.class, b.rollNo, b.support, b.grade
FROM   TABLE-B b 
       LEFT JOIN TABLE-A a 
          ON a.RollNo = b.RollNo
WHERE  a.RollNo IS NULL
```

Comment: in this approach the RollNo duplicates......thats no good.

Comment: Have you tried with `union` in place of `union all`. I don't know if it is supported.

Comment: @PrateekRaj I left out the where on the second query. I updated the query and it should work now.